# Some css is broken on developer story page

Tags: bug, design, developer-story

Some css is broken on developer story page (Recommended reading section).

Browser: Google Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Link and text heading out of designed box.

[image]

Comment: You're really supposed to give the link a title, that will fix the issue, though I agree it could do with being fixed.